# How to pass the model as a redirect attribute in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
redirectModel.addAttribute("Model", model);
return REDIRECT_PREFIX + "../../my-company/organization-management/manage-users";
```

when I pass this I get conversion exception: Cannot convert `list<?>` to `string`

Comment: what is REDIRECT_PREFIX ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we will be able to help you.

Comment: REDIRECT_PREFIX  is nothing but a constant url prefix  before a redirect url. @vipincp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) Add RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes to the method parameter list in the first controller:

```
public String test(
                @ModelAttribute("userModel") final Object UserModel,
                final BindingResult bindingResult,
                final Model model, 
                final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
```

ii) Inside the method, add code to add a flash attribute to redirectAttributes:

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userModel", mapping1FormObject);
```

iii) Then, in the second contoller use method parameter annotated with @ModelAttribute to access the redirected attributes:

```
@ModelAttribute("userModel") final Object userModel
```

Finally your two controller methods look like:

```
// Controller1

@RequestMapping(value = { "/page1" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test1(
                @ModelAttribute("userModel") final Object userModel,
                final BindingResult bindingResult,
                final Model model, 
                final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userModel", mapping1FormObject);
    return "redirect:page2";
} 

// Controller2

@RequestMapping(value = "/page2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test2(
                @ModelAttribute("userModel") final Object userModel,
                final BindingResult bindingResult,
                final Model model) {
    return "new/view";  
}
```