# What might cause a session ID to sometimes change after redirect (Java/Kotlin Spring web app)?

Tags: spring, kotlin, session, web, cookies

I have a web application built with Kotlin+Spring which identifies users by session ID. On a static front page I have a form which, on submit, sends a POST request to "/start". This is handled by Spring by executing some code and redirecting user to another page "/page" – here's the minimal code:

```
@Controller
class SomeController() {
    // No GetMapping("/"), because '/' is 100% static

    @PostMapping("/start")
    fun start(@ModelAttribute someModelAttr: SomeModelAttr, model: Model,
              response: HttpServletResponse,
              session: HttpSession) {
        log.info { "POST /start visited by ${session.id}" }
        val id = getSomeStuffSynchronously(someModelAttr, session.id);
        response.sendRedirect("page/${id}")
    }

    @GetMapping("/page/{id}")
    fun page(@PathVariable id: String,
             model: Model,
             session: HttpSession) {
        log.info { "GET /page/${id} visited by ${session.id}" }
        doOtherStuff(id, session.id);
        return "page" // i.e. render a Thymeleaf template
    }
```

The code above assumes that the session ID in `start` and `page` is the same. However, **sometimes** (but not always) this is false which breaks stuff for the users. In this situation, the log lines are basically:

```
POST /start visited by abcd
Log from getSomeStuffSynchronously(someModelAttr, "abcd")
GET /page/123 visited by vxyz
```

Unfortunately I could not capture headers sent and received by the browser when this happens, because when I tried, I could not reproduce this issue.
I've checked:

- This issue might happen regardless of whether the user uses incognito mode in their browser, or not
- I have not yet observed this happening on other requests than front-page->/start->/page/id
- I do not have caching enabled neither at my hosting provider nor in Spring
- I do not have a huge load on my website
- I do not use spring-security

Sessions are Cookie sessions and are managed by spring-session-redis, with timeout in Redis set to 15 minutes. However I did not see any obvious correlation between the time between visits to the site and this issue happening.

My question is: what might cause the session ID to change *during* the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on session.id is unreliable between redirects, but as a work-around one can use `RedirectAttributes` and store relevant data that will be needed in the second request handler as flash attributes – see e.g. [How to pass the model as a redirect attribute in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626038/how-to-pass-the-model-as-a-redirect-attribute-in-spring)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for getting a different sessions, might be because the cookie/url param containing a reference to the session might not have been set/is used (so a new session is generated every time).

It might be an obvious question but are you sure the filter responsible for handling the session is registered? E.g. did you add the `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation to a configuration class (see [redig http session docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-redis.html#httpsession-spring-configuration))?

Comment: That was not the case in my issue, however I think it's a reasonable suggestion if someone else stumbles upon this